# Hooking into Phpadmin import feature

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I've built a small cms for a client, and they want the ability to upload excel files into a mysql database, which is currently being done every other day by logging into the server and using phpadmin.

Is there a way I can "hook" into phpadmin and have my clients import this spreadsheet in a secure admin section of a website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several popular solutions for reading Excel sheets with PHP, although I prefer [this one](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/).  Once you've pulled the data in, writing some structured queries to insert it into MySQL is simple.